# Can't boot windows 8 install from usb, thinks it's a hard drive. Now stuck on win8 logo

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-installation

I have a usb flash drive I used to install windows 8 on this laptop. Now I wanna try it on my pc. In boot order there is no clear USB, there were only 3 options (tried them all) Hard, CD, Removable. I noticed that the boot system saw my usb as a hard drive (I have 2 hards, the third was my usb in that list).

So I moved my usb as the first hard, then chose to boot from hard. Now I'm stuck at the windows 8 logo on a black background. What could I do ?

**To clarify:**

When I noticed that it was recognised as a hard, I moved it to #1 position, then booted from hard, it worked. But nothing happened. There was the Win8 logo but it would not get past it. Now I recently used this usb on my laptop, no problem. Also @laptop it was viewed as an USB not a hard drive.

**EDIT:**

I installed it without booting (I really want / need a clean install) NOW it is no longer among my hard drives, but it still won't boot. No matter what I try.

I have a M2N32-SLI Deluxe motherboard

Comment: Are you trying to boot from the USB stick when you get the win8 logo problem? Or have you taken it out and are trying to boot to your normal HDD?

Comment: @MarcusChan I am booting from the usb. I get to the logo hoping install to start, nothing.

Comment: And whatever the current issue is, the way you generally want to boot to USB if you have issues is by manually selecting the USB stick in the startup options menu (usually accessed by hitting f11, f12, or some similar key when booting the machine up).

Comment: You really need to clarify what you're talking about for us to be able to help here. What exactly did you do? What do you mean by "I moved my usb as the first hard"? What "still won't boot"?

Comment: I have 3 options in my boot priority: Removable (guessing that's usb) hard and cd. I don't know what to do, I have a boot order of four (these three options in 4 positions if you understand) and I set all 4 to usb, all that happens is that it gives me an error about being unable to boot, if not all 4 on usb then it simply starts windows up

Comment: @MarcusChan I had a list of 3 hard drives, 2 were real, 1 was the usb. I moved the USB to the first boot position (upper most) and hoped to boot from "hard". Got stuck on splash screen.

Comment: Okay, try what I suggested: stop messing with your boot order in BIOS and try to access the startup options menu and manually select your USB stick.

Comment: @MarcusChan I have no idea what you just said

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7425/discussion-between-marcus-chan-and-kalec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sharkyforums.com/showthread.php?307284-Boot-Options-for-an-Asus-M2N-SLI-Deluxe

After a chat discussion, @Kalec and I found this forum post (and others), which suggest that it's an issue with that specific motherboard model, specifically that it can't mount anything from USB.

Comment: If someone on SU knows how to fix that, though, that would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just wait a while (long time).

I just stucked at Windows logo for about 20 mins tonight, and then installation UI shown.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer to the OP questions, not even a comment. Please read the site's guidelines to understand how to post a nice answer or comment.